# Avoid using command for keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, services, shortcut-menu

I work with a disabled person who uses their communication-aid to control their iMac through keyboard and mouse commands.

I'm setting up keyboard shortcuts to launch applications directly using services in Automator, however the communication-aid doesn't have the ability to send the command key.

How can I get OSX to recognise other key combinations? (e.g. ctrl-alt-f to launch FireFox)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/craete-your-own-keyboard-shortcuts.php) explains how to customize keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

[Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) allows you to open applications by speech, not to mention all of the other benefits of working via speech when there are motor-issues to consider.

Comment: Dragon listens to speech; the person I'm working is unable to speak. I'm looking for a method that reads tricky paragraphs to him.